# map DTO to Backend Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping, dto

I am developing a rest application where the data in DB is loaded in Entities then some transformations are made on the data while being filled in corresponding DTOs then returned back to the consumer.

According to the consumer and some other parameters, a different subset of the data should be returned to the user, for example if user is inquiring on his personal info, level of details returning will be different than if a manager is inquiring on the data of his employees, etc ...

My question:
Is there any framework to handle this custom mapping (i.e. an xml based file that determines which field in which BE Entity should be mapped to which DTO in which condition ? instead of making a custom code in each case? thanks in advance.

I am using spring rest + hibernate

Answer (score 2):

About XML file mapping, I do not know any. But what I find really useful and very customizable is [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/). It is a very useful library and the docs and examples are very good.

A simple example:

```java
@Mapper 
public interface CarMapper {
 
    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CarMapper.class ); 
 
    @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount") // Here is one of the functionalities that you wanted...
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car); 
}
```

And there is IDE and Lombok support also.

Comment: thanks ... however I need to implement `carToCarDto` method -and any other if I have multiple mappings- ... right?

Comment: No, MapStruct will implement them for you, you just need to have getters and setters. Check the examples and the website that I linked in the answer. It does exactly what you need